# How to trace/outline objects in an image?

Tags: image, image-processing, google-mlkit

I am hoping to learn more about how to go about tracing an object in an image. For example, if I wasn’t to trace the outline of a person.

Are there tools like ML Kit that would be able to accomplish this on a device or do I need to send the image server side and process in the backend. I’m more familiar with JavaScript but initial searches are pointing to python.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to trace the outline of an object/person in an image, you will need object/person segmentation. ML Kit does not currently support that, but we are working on selfie segmentation and will soon invite developers to participate in our [Early Access Program (EAP)](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/early-access). It's intended for selfie. For tracing the outline of other scenario including non-human objects, you may want to search for a custom segmentation model, e.g. on [TensorFlow Hub](https://tfhub.dev/s?module-type=image-segmentation), which you can run using TFLite directly on a device.